# Output pretty html in swig

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

How can I output pretty HTML using Swig in Express? I have tried the following:

- `app.set('view options', { pretty: true });`
- `app.locals.pretty = true;`
- using Production environment

My view code looks like this:

```js
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'swig');
app.engine('.swig', swig.renderFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with swig Filter. example: {{character|safe}}
you can get more here http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/filters/

Comment: None of these pretty print html